# Markov chains - Why is this a distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

I read about markov chains here : https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos521/markov.pdf .

There was something I didn't understand at the beginning of page 6, 
the last inequality, with the $A_iE_i$ and $L_2$ norm.[image]

From what I understand, they mean that $x - v_1 (\frac{1}{n})$ (where $v_1 $is the $(1,1,...,1)$ vector), is a distribution.  But how come? $x$ is a distribution and we deduct a vector whose coordinates sum to $1$.

Why is $x - v_1(\frac{1}{n})$ (or sum of  $A_iE_i$ from $i=2$ to $n$) , a distribution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x$ is a distribution, $Mx$ is too, since $M$ is a transition matrix.

Note that its stationary distribution is $s=(1/n)\vec{1}$. But $s$ is the first eigenvector of $M$ (by definition of stationary distribution given), with eigenvalue $1$ (so $Ms=s$). In other words $e_1=s$ and since the eigenvectors form a complete system, you can write:
$$
x = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i = s + \sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i e_i
$$
using the observation (in the notes) that $\alpha_1=1$.

Now:
$$
Mx = M\left(s+\sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i e_i\right)=
Ms+\sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i M e_i
= s+\sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i \lambda_i e_i
$$
is a distribution (since $Mx$ is one). So $M^tx$ is also one.
Repeatedly applying our rule above gives:
$$
M^tx = s + \sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i \lambda_i^t e_i
$$
The author is interested in *how fast* $ M^tx $ converges to $s$. So he looks at and bounds
$$
||M^tx - s||_2 = ||s + \sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i \lambda_i^t e_i - s||_2
= ||\sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i \lambda_i^t e_i||_2
$$
which is the $\ell_2$ distance of the distribution $M^tx$ from $s$, for some $t$.

The quantity in the norm is not a distribution; rather, it is the distance between two discrete distributions.

---

Edit: it seems the asker's actual question is why 
$||\sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i e_i||_2 \leq 1$. I'll show that now:
\begin{align}
|| \sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i e_i  ||_2^2
&=
||x - s||_2^2 \\
&= 
\sum_i \left( x_i - \frac{1}{n} \right)^2 \\
&=
\sum_i x_i^2 - \frac{2x_i}{n} +\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=
||x_i||_2^2 - \frac{2}{n}\sum_i x_i +\frac{1}{n}\\
&=
||x_i||_2^2 - \frac{1}{n}\\
&\leq
||x_i||_1^2 - \frac{1}{n}\\
&\leq
1 - \frac{1}{n}\\
&\leq 1
\end{align}

Comment: What I don't understand, is why the norm : $||\sum_{i=2}^n \alpha_i  e_i||_2$ less than / equal to 1. Suppose we have 2 vectors $(1,0,...,0)$ , $(0,1,...,0)$. Both are distributions but their L2 norm is the root of 2, which is larger than 1...

Comment: @Bar What do you mean? If $a_i(j)=\delta_{ij}$ is the unit vector with all zeroes except a 1 at the $i$ position, then $||a_i||_2=1$. $||a_i + a_k||_2=\sqrt{2}$ though. But in any case where is it claimed that $|| \sum_{i=2}^n\alpha_ie_i || \leq 1$? What is claimed/used is that $||x||_2 \leq ||x||_1=1$.

Comment: @Bar I think I understood your question; see the edits above.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks!